# Applying sine orthogonality

Tags: fourier-analysis, orthonormal

I have a confusion as to why this is a viable procedure in the following image:

$$
\sum_{n} B_n \int_{0}^{a} \sin \left( \frac{n \pi x}{a}\right) \sin \left( \frac{m \pi x}{a}\right)
= \sum_{n} B_n \left( \frac{a}{2} \right) \delta_m
= \frac{a B_m}{2}
$$

To my knowledge (which is likely the thing that needs to improve here), sine orthogonality can be applied when integrating $sin(m k x) sin(n kx)$ over a full period (where $m, n$ are integers, and $k$ is a wavenumber, where $k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$), not half of one.

Here the period is clearly $2a$, so why is this permissible as well? It seems I don't know *when* and *when I can't* apply sine orthogonality given certain limits of integration and wavenumbers.

Comment: Why don't you just compute the integral explicitly? A sine addition formula will let you do this.

Comment: I certainly agree that the integral does turn out to be $a/2$, but I'm looking for a heuristic answer, basically. I don't want to have to check if my integral is equal to $\delta_{nm}$ manually each time.

Comment: Notice that the product of these two sine functions is **even**, so integrating over $[0, a]$ is the same as integrating over $[-a, 0]$. So you get half the value of integrating over a full period.

Comment: That's a good point. The context for the image is that we're considering $0 \le x \le a$, so perhaps this is the motivation for this. So, here, the assumption that we must integrate over a full period for orthogonality is correct, but my lecturer is basically stating $\int_0^a \text{even function of x} \ dx = 1/2 \int_0^{2a} \text{even function of x} \ dx $? So I am true about having to integrate over a full period, I'm just forgetting the implicit step there?

Comment: Am I right in assuming this applies to any fraction of $2a$, not just $\frac{2a}{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

Your eigenfunctions are solutions of
$$
                 y''+\lambda y = 0,\;\;\; 0 \le x \le a \\
               y(0) = 0,\;\; y(a)=0.
$$
That is,
$y_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x/a)$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ are the solutions where $\lambda_n=n^2\pi^2/a^2$. These are automatically orthogonal because of the selfadjoint nature of this ODE. And they form an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,a]$.

Likewise, $y_n(x)=\cos(n\pi x/a)$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$ are solutions of
$$
       y''+\lambda y= 0,\;\;\; 0 \le x \le a \\
        y'(0)=0,\;\; y'(a)=0
$$
So these functions also form an orthogonal basis of $L^2[0,a]$.

There are also orthogonal bases of $\sin$ functions with non-harmonic arguments that form an orthogonal basis. For example, consider the more general problem
$$
         y''+\lambda y = 0,\;\;\; 0 \le x \le a \\
         y(0)=0,\;\;\; Ay(a)+By'(a)=0.
$$
The functions $\sin(\alpha_n x)$ are solutions where
$$
     A\sin(\alpha_n a)+B\alpha_n\cos(\alpha_n a)=0
$$
The solutions $\alpha_n$ are not evenly spaced, but the corresponding $\sin(\alpha_a x)$ are mutually orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a function $f\in L^2[0,a]$ and you extend this to an odd function $f_o \in L^2[-a,a]$, and then you expand this function in a Fourier series on $[-a,a]$, you get your sine series for $f$ on $[0,a]$.

Similarly, if you extend $f$ to an even function $f_e$, then you get an expansion of $f$ on $[0,a]$ in terms of cosines $\cos(n\pi x/a)$.